# CommandBinding relative path

Tags: c#, wpf, command, commandbinding

Within my window (let's say `MyCanvas`) there's a new command definition which I then bind to my window. Usually the handlers for `CanExecute` and Executed are directly within `MyCanvas`. But is it somehow  possible to bind the `CanExecute` and `Executed` handlers to a relative path like for example `MyCanvas.Logic.CanExecute_OpenCamera`?

This is my current XAML.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="OpenCamera" Text="Open camera" />
</Window.Resources>    
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource OpenCamera}" CanExecute="CanExecute_OpenCamera" Executed="Executed_OpenCamera"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

This is what I'm trying to define. Logic is public property of MyCanvas.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="OpenCamera" Text="Open camera" />
</Window.Resources>    
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource OpenCamera}" CanExecute="Logic.CanExecute_OpenCamera" Executed="Logic.Executed_OpenCamera"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: the relative path? you mean like a NameSpace?

Comment: Yes, somehow. The command callbacks are defined in a class which I use in my window.

Comment: you can't do that because CanExecute and Execute are events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you have to use converters which create delegates to the respective methods from a bound object of the class, or from its type, if the methods are static. See http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/commanding-binding-controls-to-methods/ for details.

Comment: Thanks. Very cool link, but looks really complicated and to easy. I better stay with my event handlers inside my window.